# Insert information in one folder, looking in other 2 folders with some conditions on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hello friends I need a help,

I thought about doing it with a QUERY to solve it, but I couldn't do this formula, because you need to search two folders and compare the data between them to insert ...

I have the folders PRIMEIRA AVALIAÇÃO, SEGUNDA AVALIAÇÃO and INDICE; I need to insert in the INDICE folder the information of the other two folders. Some people who did the first assessment did not come for the second assessment. In the example spreadsheet the link below shows what happens, the PRIMEIRA AVALIAÇÃO folder has 8 lines (1 person per line) and in the SEGUNDA AVALIAÇÃO folder it has only 5 lines (1 person per line), so 3 did not come in the second assessment:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1byxU0mNQAK4ppqH9gve4xh-dqNd6fQSGjzm7CN7lbmY/edit?usp=sharing

I need to include all the columns below the PRIMEIRA AVALIAÇÃO folder in the respective columns in the INDICE folder,

COLUMN A INDICE, SEARCH FOR THE PRIMEIRA AVALIAÇÃO COLUMN G

COLUMN B INDICE, SEARCH FOR THE PRIMEIRA AVALIAÇÃO COLUMN F

COLUMN C INDICE, SEARCH FOR THE PRIMEIRA AVALIAÇÃO COLUMN D

COLUMN E INDICE, SEARCH FOR THE PRIMEIRA AVALIAÇÃO COLUMN E

COLUMN F INDICE, SEARCH FOR THE PRIMEIRA AVALIAÇÃO COLUMN J

COLUMN H INDICE, SEARCH FOR THE PRIMEIRA AVALIAÇÃO COLUMN L

COLUMN J INDICE, SEARCH FOR THE PRIMEIRA AVALIAÇÃO COLUMN K

COLUMN L INDICE, SEARCH FOR THE PRIMEIRA AVALIAÇÃO COLUMN M

COLUMN N INDICE, SEARCH FOR THE PRIMEIRA AVALIAÇÃO COLUMN O

COLUMN P INDICE, SEARCH FOR THE PRIMEIRA AVALIAÇÃO COLUMN P

COLUMN R INDICE, SEARCH FOR THE PRIMEIRA AVALIAÇÃO COLUMN S

After that, include the information from the SEGUNDA AVALIAÇÃO folder in the INDICE folder and the condition would be to search for the “nome completo do desafiado” that is in the INDICE folder (column A) then check if it exists in the SEGUNDA AVALIAÇÃO folder (column G), if true, copy these columns below for the line with “nome completo do desafiado” where you have the name you searched for in the INDICE folder:

COLUMN D INDICE, SEARCH FOR THE SEGUNDA AVALIAÇÃO COLUMN D

COLUMN G INDICE, SEARCH FOR THE SEGUNDA AVALIAÇÃO COLUMN H

COLUMN I INDICE, SEARCH FOR THE SEGUNDA AVALIAÇÃO COLUMN J

COLUMN K INDICE, SEARCH FOR THE SEGUNDA AVALIAÇÃO COLUMN I

COLUMN M INDICE, SEARCH FOR THE SEGUNDA AVALIAÇÃO COLUMN K

COLUMN O INDICE, SEARCH FOR THE SEGUNDA AVALIAÇÃO COLUMN M

COLUMN Q INDICE, SEARCH FOR THE SEGUNDA AVALIAÇÃO COLUMN N

COLUMN S INDICE, SEARCH FOR THE SEGUNDA AVALIAÇÃO COLUMN Q

If the “nome completo do desafiado” does not exist in the SEGUNDA AVALIAÇÃO(column G) folder it is to leave the columns above referring to the line with the “nome completo do desafiado” (column A)in the INDICE folder with empty values(column D,G,I,K,M,O,Q,S)

Thanks help

Comment: Are you open to doing this in Google Apps Script? Could you show what you tried till now?

Comment: Hello thanks for your interest in helping! 
Of course I am open to using scripts if I can help I am grateful.
I had made a simple formula by importing the information from folder PRIMEIRA PESAGEM and SEGUNDA PESAGEM into the folder that consolidates the data that has the name INDICE, but it didn't work out for the reasons I informed in the previous post.

reasons I informed in the previous post

Comment: Hello, I was able to solve it using the VLOOKUP function, I had to change the column to search key to position it in column A and I did the necessary searches and it worked.

Comment: Hi, since you found a solution to your problem, I'd suggest you to post an answer explaining this, since it can be useful for other people in the community.

Comment: I meant posting an answer, not a comment. Check the `Post Your Answer` button below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I will follow your suggestion, I used the formula below: =if(A7="";"";(vlookup($A7;'PRIMEIRA AVALIAÇÃO'!$A:$T;6;0))) where A7 is the name I need to look for, in the formula it says that if A7 is empty it returns empty, if it doesn't execute the function ... vlookup says the following, A7 is the name I need to find, where to find it? in the folder where the information is found, then what is the search range, then the number 6 means to bring what is in column 6 that would be column F, then 0 means that it needs to be exactly the same